# SmsManager causes com.android.phone force closes randomly

Tags: android, text, sms

I am using SmsManager to send text messages from my application. The code snippet is

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, content, null, null);
```

For messages with less than 160 characters. And for multipart messages I use,

```
ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(content);
sMan.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, parts, null, null);
```

These statements cause The process com.android.phone has stopped unexpectedly please try again in a random fashion. I don't understand what's going on.

This is the stack trace I got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at com.android.internal.telephony.SMSDispatcher.handleSendComplete(SMSDispatcher.java:741)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at com.android.internal.telephony.SMSDispatcher.handleMessage(SMSDispatcher.java:407)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4603)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1143):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, content, null, null);
```

Technically the *null* parameters for the **sentIntent** and **deliveredIntent** shouldn't cause any problems. But that's not the case with my application. I have seen many applications in the Android market with the same issue and users giving them 1 star rating. I repaced the null parameters with insignificant intents and now don't have trouble using them.

```
PendingIntent sent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
PendingIntent delivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, content, sent, delivered);
```

Now the code works fine.